# Laravel - Querys are not returning right results when made inside a observer class

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, I have a observer class being observed by a Question model with this "delete" method:

```
class QuestionObserver {
[...]
public function deleted(Question $question)
     {
        $allQuestionFiles = QuestionFiles:all();
        dd($questionFiles);
    }
}
```

The observer event is being fired correctly, but the query being executed somehow does not return all the records it should, idk how but the result is returned 1 record smaller than it should.

I tried to execute the exact same query in a controller, to test if the problem was happening only at the observer method, and on the controller, the query returned all the records.

Comment: has one less record ... like it isn't including the record you just deleted?

Comment: No, because I`m trying to query the table question_files while having deleted a record from the questions table.